# Looking for a strategy to implement publish capability via email

Tags: email, mime-types, content-type, mime, content-disposition

Imagine you want to provide the ability to publish news on your website sending an email to a given address (like for example publish.news@domain.com).

1) The base strategy is: look for something that **is text/html and not disposition**, and this is the primary body of the email.

2) Then look for any other content that **is disposition** and **is attachment** (and you'll get all the attachments).

3) Discard any other content that **is disposition and inline** because, correct me if i'm wrong, it's kinda stuff like email signature and thus not needed.

So far so good this strategy works good. However i don't know how to:

- deal with **multipart/alternative** content. Some clients seems to compose HTML with this primary/subtype content-type.
- deal with **multipart/mixed** (even don't know what it means).
- if any email clients let to compose in html adding your own images and encoding them in some way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multipart/alternative` just means that each part is an alternative version of the same thing, just with a different content type (say, an HTML version and a plaintext version).

`multipart/mixed` is used to put different content types inline.  This will allow a client to put (say) an image inline in a message that is otherwise (say) plaintext.

You can read about all the multipart MIME types in the spec at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1 or in [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).

Comment: So it seems i have to inspect also if it's multipart/mixed to have a complete working html copy of a message?